# Microsoft Teams | Team Calendar Dashboard Control | Fluent UI

Tags: microsoft-teams, fluentui-react

I'm currently working on developing a Microsoft Teams Tab App. One of the essential features is to showcase meetings through a calendar dashboard. I'm interested in utilizing the same Calendar Dashboard control that MS Teams employs for displaying their calendar (refer to the attached screenshot).

I am using Fluent UI React Components - https://react.fluentui.dev/?path=/docs/compat-components-calendar--default for all the controls.

It has a calendar component, but it only does the date selection.

Any idea if there is a Calendar Dhashbard control available?
[image]

Comment: @QaiserMajeed, I didn't find the Team's control that I was expecting but I did found couple of other controls that I will be using in future for my requirements: 
 https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/blazing-pond-47crhl?file=%2Fsrc%2FFullCalendar.js
 & 
https://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/story/about-big-calendar--page